# Garage door opener works with remote but not switch

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I have a 20-year-old Python Garage door opener. Worked fine.

I decided to add an additional "push-button" dry contact relay to the mix so I could operate it with my phone. After unplugging it, I hooked up the wires (22-guage stranded security wire) and tested it and it wouldn't operate.

After other tests, I tried shorting the two screws with a short wire. No joy.

The car (RF) remote works fine, so the safety sensors must be working.

I did this to an identical opener (I have three...) and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sidenote -- there are special requirements for unattended operation safety in the UL 325 standard, including visible and audible alerting in the garage, as well as a "lockout" if the door doesn't go down after two unattended attempts.  See [this UL article](https://www.ul.com/news/convenience-and-safety-working-together-unattended-operation-residential-garage-door-operators) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I finally removed the "dry contact relay" wires, tested them for continuity, and reattached them in reverse. It all worked. My suspicion is that the "dry contact relays" have a "common common", meaning all the relays rely on a joint "common" (even though they all have a separate common terminal....) So, when I connected the relay reverse of how I connected the other garage door opener, I inadvertently ended up "shorting" the second garage door opener. Still not sure why it worked that way, but all's well that ends well, eh?

Comment: Sounds like the supposed "relay" isn't a relay at all, but is some sort of electronics which cares about polarity or common.  Since your motivation is to control it *with your phone*, and smart phones can't control normal relays, it sounds like this is some sort of uber-smart gizmo anyway, possibly a "cheap Cheese" non-UL-listed thing (which I don't care about if only low voltage is involved).  The cheapos always take shortcuts like using semiconductors instead of mechanicals, or not isolating things which are normally isolated.

Comment: The relay pack is a Sonoff 4Ch Pro. Very popular and common, but often used for other purposes, and in different configurations. I have found no docs that say its commons are tied, but lots of docs where tied commons are used. I can't say for sure this is the issue. I may have somehow shorted a terminal to another one, or some other issue. Only low voltage is involved.

Comment: Yeah, it's popular because it's cheap, and it's cheap because it doesn't go the extra mile to conform with industrial design standards or certifications.  A teardown would tell for sure,  but it could also be a solid-state "relay" that does not isolate as much as a mechanical one does.